# Android simply use Realm to save and get saved results doesnt work

Tags: android, realm

i'm newbie in Realm database solution and i want to use that in my application, but after test codes during read the realm documents my codes doesn't work and my `result` return zero record.

**Application:**

```
public class EManApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .name("EmanClient.db")
                .build();

        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);

    }
}
```

**manifest:**

```
<application
    android:name=".EManApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

**UserAccountInfo model:**

```
public class UserAccountInfo extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String userId;
    private String name;
    private String family;
    private String mobileNumber;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFamily() {
        return family;
    }

    public void setFamily(String family) {
        this.family = family;
    }

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
// Defined realm field   
private Realm realm;

/*OnCreate*/
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

realm.beginTransaction();

UserAccountInfo userAccountInfo = new UserAccountInfo();
userAccountInfo.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
userAccountInfo.setUserId("1");
userAccountInfo.setName("MyName");
userAccountInfo.setFamily("MyFamily");
userAccountInfo.setMobileNumber("+98746321");

realm.commitTransaction();

RealmResults<UserAccountInfo> results = realm.where(UserAccountInfo.class).findAll();
for (UserAccountInfo u : results) {
    Log.e("", u.getId());
}
```

in this above get result `results` variable is zero

Comment: You are not inserting the object to realm

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `copyToRealm` to add a new realm object:

```
realm.beginTransaction();

UserAccountInfo userAccountInfo = new UserAccountInfo();
userAccountInfo.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
userAccountInfo.setUserId("1");
userAccountInfo.setName("MyName");
userAccountInfo.setFamily("MyFamily");
userAccountInfo.setMobileNumber("+98746321");

realm.copyToRealm(userAccountInfo); // add this line

realm.commitTransaction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to @Fabio's answer

`new UserAccountInfo();`

should be replaced with

`realm.createObject(UserAccountInfo.class);`

Comment: He has ID so he should use `realm.createObject(UserAccountInfo.class, userId)`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks for downvoating my answer. You can set primary key value using setId() method as well Instead of setting it in constructor.

Comment: Except your code will result in this same issue https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2939#issuecomment-224610580